# Extending model class causes Column not found error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

I have created a new class which extends the `Role` class. Here is the code for `Role`:

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\Permission\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasPermissions;
use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist;
use Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role as RoleContract;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\RefreshesPermissionCache;

class Role extends Model implements RoleContract
{
    use HasPermissions;
    use RefreshesPermissionCache;

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     */
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->setTable(config('laravel-permission.table_names.roles'));
    }

    /**
     * A role may be given various permissions.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            config('laravel-permission.models.permission'),
            config('laravel-permission.table_names.role_has_permissions')
        );
    }

    /**
     * A role may be assigned to various users.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            config('auth.model') ?: config('auth.providers.users.model'),
            config('laravel-permission.table_names.user_has_roles')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Find a role by its name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @throws RoleDoesNotExist
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public static function findByName($name)
    {
        $role = static::where('name', $name)->first();

        if (! $role) {
            throw new RoleDoesNotExist();
        }

        return $role;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user may perform the given permission.
     *
     * @param string|Permission $permission
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasPermissionTo($permission)
    {
        if (is_string($permission)) {
            $permission = app(Permission::class)->findByName($permission);
        }

        return $this->permissions->contains('id', $permission->id);
    }
}
```

My code was working fine when accessing this `Role` class directly for `create()`'s, but attempting to perform the same tasks using my new `UserRole` class, I am getting `Column not found` database errors when attempting to create a new `Role`.

Here is the `UserRole` class:

```
namespace App;

use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

class UserRole extends Role
{
    use LogsActivity;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be logged.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $logAttributes = ['name', 'permissions'];
}
```

So `Role::create()` works fine, but `UserRole::create()` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well changing the name to `Role` and then changing my use clause to `as SpatieRole` has fixed the issue. I'm guessing it was some type of class name relationship issue with Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define the `$table` property on your Eloquent model, the table name is derived from the name of the Model. So, the `Role` model would use the `roles` table by default. The `UserRole` model would look for the `user_roles` table by default.

Since you still want to use the same table, but your model name is changed, you will need to define the `$table` property on your new model to make it look at the `roles` table.

```
class UserRole extends Role
{
    protected $table = 'roles';

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that. While it worked for the main table, all of the relational table queries got messed up, even with having their table names declared in the inherited model.

Comment: @kjdion84 did you publish the package config file and change the `model.role` key to point to your custom model?